# how to get required label from string of objects

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my code-igniter application, I have an string that contains `json` objects. each object has value and label, and I want to get the label from an object where the value matches. Please tell how can I do that?

**String:**

```
$my_string = '{value:"123",label:"example"},{value:"321",label:"required label"}';
```

Comment: Run a foreach loop over your json_object. If you have tried any code post that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `json_decode` and `foreach` for that like this :

Working demo : https://eval.in/1008536

```
/*your json string should be like this */
$my_string='[{"value":"123","label":"example"},{"value":"321","label":"required label"}]'; 

$arr = json_decode($my_string,true);

if ( ! empty($arr))
{
    foreach ($arr as $item) {

       if ($item['value'] == '321')
       {
           $label = $item['label'];
       }

    }
}

echo $label;

/* Output : required label*/
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php